Upgrade to 24.04 from 23.10
When I click the upgrade option I get a message saying “update failed - kde daemon” with zero content in the dialogue box. I have the software updater prompt and when I click to upgrade I get the empty message described above.

Does this answer your question? Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 or 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04

It's not a duplicate of that.

Try upgrading from the command like sudo do-release-upgrade. If there is an error, tell us what is the output

I just completed the upgrade, May 25, using  the sudo do-release-upgrade command. I upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04. Took several minutes and did require my affirmative response to a few prompts and a restart of course.

Tried “sudo do-release-upgrade” and got this: please install all available updates for your release before upgrading. I updated with sudo apt-get update and got the same message.

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
